# Change localhost URL of magento to access it globally

Tags: magento-1.8

I need to change my localhost url http://localhost:1338/magento2

to **abc.mycompany.com**.

So my URL is accessible globally ie outside my localhost

Final URL should be:

**abc.mycompany.com/magento2**

1) I tried changing in core_config_data web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to abc.mycompany.com/magento2

2) Added 127.0.0.1 abc.mycompany.com in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

But my site is not loading.

Pls suggest.

Comment: after doing this stuff you can access your site locally via your domain name not globally

Comment: And also this qustion on bases of server related settings not related to magento

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I misunderstood you, but if not:
I'm afraid that you need to learn, what DNS, etc/hosts and IPs are.

Your computer has an IP address if you can access the internet. But usually this is an "internal" ip, which means you have a router to access the internet which does "NATing". This means you can access the internet, but the internet can't access you (not quite correct but enough for the moment).

Therefore the problem is, that the internet doesn't access to your machine. The local network might have (if you don't have a firewall which prohibits that.

Ok, so you need a globally accessable IP address, no NATted to be able to serve your magento to the world. This can be done through port forwarding too.

Assuming we have a globally accessable IP address, then AND ONLY THEN, you cann make it accessable via a domain name. To do this, you have to add a A, AAAA or CNAME entry to your DNS.

A DNS-Service is kind of a telephone book. You can only call people if you know their number, but the book translates the name to a number.

your `hosts` file is doing the same, but only you are allowed to write entries to it.

I hope I didn't offend you and it helps understanding. In case I got you totally wrong, sorry for starting with Adam and Eve.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, got some idea, will dig on it...

Answer (score 2):

Run `ipconfig /flushdns` in the command prompt and then clear the browser cache. Then the shop is accessible through `http://abc.mycompany.com:1338/magento2` (the hosts file only assigns a host name to an IP address, port and subdirectory are still the same. So you will have to change the base URLs to `http://abc.mycompany.com:1338/magento2/`

And since you wrote "access it globally", just in case it was not clear: this only works on your computer. `etc/hosts` does not magically turn your PC into a public web server.

Comment: Yes is there way how to make my server into public, like i need to access my local in a mobile device or in another computer of diff network... alternatively im trying ngrok, but still redirects to my localhost...

Comment: There are ways to do this, but it's dangerous and you should know exactly what you are doing. No offense, but with your level of knowledge it would be irresponsible and chances are you'll get hacked in no time. Better put the site on a real test server

Comment: Yes i understand,and the main purpose of this is to share my test site for demo purpose and no offense too, dont know why many ppl degrade others here...Anyway thanks for ur suggestion

Comment: @SachinS just don't turn your computer into a webserver, the risks are too high and if you're not a professional hoster, chances are you'll get Ddos in a minute. If you want to share stuff, just use teamviewer or remote desktop connection to let someone access your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have inserted wrong value in your host file. The correct value will be

127.0.0.1 abc.mycompany.com/magento2

After making this change, don't forget to restart your server.